# How to prove that $\mathbb{E}(c*X)=c*\mathbb{E}(X)$ using the definition of expectation $\mathbb{E}(X)$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Please someone help me to prove the following theorem:
$$\mathbb{E}(c*X)=c*\mathbb{E}(X)$$
using the definition of expectation $$\mathbb{E}(X)$$:
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iP(x_i)$$

Comment: If $X$ can take value $x_{1}$ with probability $p(x_{1})$, $x_{2}$ with probability $p(x_{2})$ etc, then $c \cdot X$ takes $c$ times the value $x_{1}$ with probability $p(x_{1})$, $c$ times the value of $x_{2}$ with probability $p(x_{2})$ etc. Now apply the expectation to $c \cdot X$.

Comment: Amusingly, the answer you accepted is **not** based on the definition you say you want to start from. In full logic, to you, $E(cX)$ should read $$E(cX)=\sum_yyP_{cX}(y)$$ (Similar remark than about your other question asking about $E(X+Y)$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. Let $X$ be a random variable with PMF $f(x)$ on the sample space $\Omega$. Now let $c$ be a scalar. Then

\begin{align*}
E(cX) &= \sum_{x \in \Omega} cxf(x) \\
&= c\sum_{x \in \Omega} xf(x) \\
&= cE(X)
\end{align*}

Done. Sums and integrals are linear so expectation is linear.

Comment: See comment on main.